# Pluralsight IQ share gives suspicious request

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, pluralsight-iq, suspicious-request

I just took a couple of IQ tests on Pluralsight and would like to insert the results into my developer story, but it keeps giving me this error:

[image]

I couldn't find any related informations about this, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170875/suspicious-login-request-when-using-google-id

Comment: @Clive unfortunately none of the answers are good, I tried everything said there, but the error still persist

Comment: I also reproduced this error.

Comment: @sanyash if you find any solution, please write it here, thank you!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: Getting the same thing.  Kind of annoying for them to be promoting pluralsight in the dev story page and then not letting you link in assessments.

Comment: the error is still present, what to do to get the right person's attention?

Comment: Same here... Please fix!

Comment: I have been facing this issue for 4 days. Any help to fix this appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue too. Any solution yet?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It's been 10 days!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this error today using Chrome on a Mac.

I solved the problem by logging out of StackOverflow (including all domains on all devices) followed by logging out of Pluralsight.  Then I logged back into Pluralsight, chose the Skill IQ I wanted to display and clicked the StackOverflow share button.

After logging into StackOverflow the skill appeared in my Developer Story, no more error message.

Comment: yep, it's working tihs way, however you have to log out and log in on StackOverFlow before every insertion which is VERY annoying. But yes, it's working, thank you for your solution! (used win 10 and chrome)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the bug report, and apologies for the delay in getting this fixed. We'd accidentally enabled XSRF protection on the API which Pluralsight calls when they send us your IQ information. Of course the request coming from Pluralsight *is* a cross-site request (it's authenticated using a shared secret). I've turned XSRF back off for that route, so everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue.