# What exactly is a Suspicious Request and what triggers it?

Tags: support, error-message, faq-proposed, suspicious-request

There have been several reports over the past few years of users occasionally getting an error message from Stack Overflow of the following form:

> Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again.

The error does not seem to be limited to a specific part of Stack Overflow. It has been observed in [login](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303580/6471538) in 2015 as well as the [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388808/6471538) in 2019.

In 2015, a [developer admitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303719/6471538) that he did not fully understand the criteria for the issuance of this error. Let's create a canonical post about this error message.

- What is a Suspicious Request?
- What triggers a Suspicious Request error message?

  - Did I do something wrong?
  - Am I under investigation?
  - Does this mean that I have been hacked?
  - Is the logic that determines if a request is suspicious embedded in a third-party utility, library, or framework (e.g. antivirus, anti-malware, firewall, etc.) or is it custom written by Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange engineers?
- Other than having my requests denied, are there any penalties for having too many of my requests deemed suspicious? Am I in danger of being Suspended?
- What can I do so that my requests are perceived less suspiciously?

Comment: Well, we don’t want to spell out exactly what makes a request suspicious because that just gives people who *are* suspicious a way around it. If it’s intermittent or rare across the broad SO population, and the fix is as simple as the message describes (“hit back and try again”), I’d say there isn’t a problem to solve here.

Comment: @DanBron that sounds like the start of an answer. More specifically, it might be helpful to explain what *kind* of bad behavior this is designed to stop - is it trying to detect hacking attempts? Posts from locations that frequently spam? Trollish behavior? Requests that are likely a part of a DDOS attack? Bots trying to scrape personal data off the site? Requests from users that are currently Suspended? People that use Stack Overflow "too much" and probably need a break?

Comment: Random guess: Suspicious requests are a part of SE's XSS protection, and Pluralsight made a request SE thought was a bad self-XSS attempt, possibly due to a bug.

Comment: @DanBron Well, the problem is obviously not intermittent or rare, as can be easily seen from the linked question about pluralsight integration. And the "hit back and try again" fix is certainly not a fix, since it doesn't work.

Comment: A small clarification that I'm not sure how to fit into an edit without ruining your post: I knew the criteria, but in investigating that specific bug report, nothing overtly obvious was wrong... which in itself was concerning since I was re-writing authentication at the time.

Comment: Still happening on login, plain Firefox from an iPhone

Answer (score 5):

This error shows up when we catch Cross-site request forgery, request forgery in general and some other attack vectors.

As for what may be causing it on legit browsing, it can be a ton of things, including a bug in our code. Barring that, it can be the result of your machine/connection being compromised somehow or a minor error. It can be that you had a page open for too long and then made a request where a validation had expired.

Then we also have the pluralsight integration that seems to be broken, as reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388808/pluralsight-iq-share-gives-suspicious-request), and we're looking into fixing it. There's an accepted answer there with a workaround for the moment.

If refreshing the page and trying again doesn't work, then providing a detailed bug report (barring the pluralsight error) that includes:

- The specific URL you were on
- The specific action you tried to take and gave you the error
- The specific time (and timezone) when it happened

This will allow us to take a look into the logs and determine if its a bug on our side, or something weirder going on.